# sendkeys doesn't work with type numbers python appium

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

**Hi everyone! I need some help, I been working on enter a number into an input field. this field is type NUMBER

First I find the element,
Sencond I click the element (this works fine)
Thrid I try to write on the fiend, but the test fail.

Here is the code.**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pages.basepage import BasePage

class medicationform(BasePage):
    dosis = (By.XPATH, "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.app.Dialog/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")


  def ingresar_dosis(self):
        self.click(self.dosis)
        self.send_keys_integer(self.dosis,2)




class BasePage:

   def send_keys_integer(self, by, text: int):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by))
        element.send_keys(text)
```

**
I attache the appium inspector

Thanks for your help.!**

I tried diferents XPATHS. also I tried in others inputs type = numbers and doesnt work. But for String types works ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `send_keys()` using anything other than string. If you MUST send your method an `int`, you can change the line below.

```
element.send_keys(str(text))
```

Otherwise I would suggest that your method accept string which makes everything easier.

```
self.send_keys_integer(self.dosis,"2")
```

If you're going to pass strings, you might as well remove (or at least rename) `.send_keys_integer()`.

Comment: I did try, using an other method, but still.                                                                                            
       def send_keys(self, by, text):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by))
        element.send_keys(text)

Comment: You stated in your question, "I tried in others inputs type = numbers and doesnt work. But for String types works ok." I've explained that you can't `send_keys()` numbers (`int`), only text/strings. I don't understand what the issue is.